# Can I have a button that is always showing but still changes the images when you click on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I followed this tutorial: https://stashable.blog/2018/12/30/make-a-dress-up-game-using-javascript-html-and-css/ and it worked perfectly, but I would like to change something.
The tutorial uses only one doll, and I have multiple dolls (for skin colors) so I treated it like the others options (shoes, pants, etc), and because of that the game appears empty at the beginning.

It is the first time I try doing something like this (well, I used to use flash for similar things when I was 10-12, but I remember almost anything and it was different I think...) and I have no clue how to do what I want. I guessed I had to change something of the ".css" file, and I tried using:

background-image: url("../img/doll1.png");

in the #doll{ part, but that doesn't allow the button to change the image.

I'm really lost here and I wans't able to find any solution or tutorial online. Please help :(

```js
var state = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
};

function nexthairback() {
  console.log("inside function nexthairback");
  console.log(state.a);
  var hairback = document.getElementById("hairback");
  if (state.a === 0) {
    hairback.setAttribute("class", "hairback1");
    state.a++;
    console.log(state.a);
  } else
  if (state.a === 1) {
    hairback.setAttribute("class", "hairback2");
    state.a = 0;
  }

}

function nextdoll() {
  console.log("inside function nextdoll");
  console.log(state.b);
  var doll = document.getElementById("doll");
  if (state.b === 0) {
    doll.setAttribute("class", "doll1");
    state.b++;
    console.log(state.b);
  } else
  if (state.b === 1) {
    doll.setAttribute("class", "doll2");
    state.b = 0;
  }

}

function nexthairfront() {
  console.log("inside function nexthairfront");
  console.log(state.c);
  var hairfront = document.getElementById("hairfront");
  if (state.c === 0) {
    hairfront.setAttribute("class", "hairfront1");
    state.c++;
    console.log(state.c);
  } else
  if (state.c === 1) {
    hairfront.setAttribute("class", "hairfront2");
    state.c = 0;
  }

}

window.onload = init;

function init() {
  console.log("window has loaded");
  state.a = 0;
  state.b = 0;
  state.c = 0;

}
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 1540px;
  background-color: white;
}

#background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1340px;
  left: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;
  background-image: url("../img/background.png");
}

#hairback {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1340px;
}

#doll {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1340px;
}

#hairfront {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1340px;
}

.doll1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1340px;
  background-image: url("../img/doll1.png");
}

.doll2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1340px;
  background-image: url("../img/doll2.png");
}

.hairback1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1340px;
  background-image: url("../img/hairback1.png");
}

.hairback2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1340px;
  background-image: url("../img/hairback2.png");
}

.hairfront1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1340px;
  background-image: url("../img/hairfront1.png");
}

.hairfront2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1340px;
  background-image: url("../img/hairfront2.png");
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<title> Dress up game</title>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="background">
      <div id="hairback"></div>
      <div id="doll"></div>
      <div id="hairfront"></div>
    </div>


    <input type="button" value="NEXT" id="nexthairback" onclick="nexthairback()">
    <input type="button" value="NEXT" id="nextdoll" onclick="nextdoll()">
    <input type="button" value="NEXT" id="nexthairfront" onclick="nexthairfront()">

  </div>

  <script src="js/code.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMlhr.png)

Comment: If you need better help, please add your code here preferably in a snippet. Otherwise add your code with images of output

Comment: How do I do that? I have to add to content of the file that says ".js"? or the ".html"? or the ".css"? or the three of them? I'm confused.

Comment: All three of them if applicable. In your case i feel HTML and JS are needed.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try adding them <3

Comment: I did it! Hope it is okay, I'm not sure what I just done qwq

Comment: Hello @BlueDots, I would also work on the indentation, I know the code is there, but you will notice such a huge difference in readability!

Comment: If you want to notify someone about changes you can use `@`  and user name after that , if you start typing you will automatically get name at top left side . I will notify @TusharShahi

Comment: Thank you @axel !!! <3

Comment: Thank you @Rana !!! <3

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow Blue Dots!

It is very unclear to me what you exactly want, but from what I understand is that you want to change the doll with a background-image right? We can do this with JavaScript.

What we first do is get the document by the ID that it has been assigned in HTML.

```
const doll = document.getElementById("doll");
```

After this, we want to change the styles right? The background-image to be specific, we can do this in JavaScript as well!

```
doll.style.backgroundImage = "url('Put your image directory here')";
```

You have to figure out for yourself now how to make this happen on a button click, aswell as making the image directory url change on the button click every time. Good Luck ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this, but I'll try anyway, thanks! if I make the doll a background-image it will always appears, right? Do you think that if I upload a picture of what happens and what I want to happens would be clearer? Thank you for all!

Comment: I added a picture that maybe helps :( sorry, English is not my first language and I'm not able to express as good as I woul want to. @SuchJitter

Comment: @Blue Dots Upload the pictures that you use to the internet and then link them in the css, the background-image that you use, then we can also use them and help you.